# app-localize-behavior and shared localization cache

Tags: localization, polymer

According to the polymer documentation for [app-localize-behavior](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/localize)

> Each element that displays content to be localized should add Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior. All of these elements share a common localization cache, **so you only need to load translations once**.

In the following snippet (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332126/app-localize-behavior-and-nested-template/37332899#37332899)) does not find the shared resources in the  tag

Maybe I missed something ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/yahoo/intl-messageformat/d361003/dist/intl-messageformat.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-toggle-button/paper-toggle-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="app-localize-behavior/app-localize-behavior.html">

</head>

<body>
  <x-local-translate></x-local-translate>

  <dom-module id="x-local-translate">
    <template>

      <div>
        <span title="english"></span>
        <paper-toggle-button on-change="_toggle" id="switch"></paper-toggle-button>
        <span title="french"></span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h4>Outside Repeater</h4>
        <div>
          <div>{{localize('greeting')}}</div>
        </div>

        <h4>Template Repeater Items</h4>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{things}}">
          <div>{{localize('greeting')}}</div>
        </template>


        <x-local-test></x-local-test>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: "x-local-translate",
        behaviors: [
          Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior
        ],
        properties: {
          things: {
            type: Array,
            value: function() {
              return [1, 2, 3];
            }
          },

          /* Overriden from AppLocalizeBehavior */
          language: {
            value: 'en',
            type: String
          },

          /* Overriden from AppLocalizeBehavior */
          resources: {
            type: Object,
            value: function() {
              return {
                'en': {
                  'greeting': 'Hello!'
                },
                'fr': {
                  'greeting': 'Bonjour!'
                }
              };
            }
          }
        },
        _toggle: function() {
          this.language = this.$.switch.checked ? 'fr' : 'en';
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="x-local-test">
    <template>
      <h4>Inside x-local-test</h4>
      <div>{{localize('greeting')}}</div>
    </template>

    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: "x-local-test",
        behaviors: [
          Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior
        ],

        properties: {
          things: {
            type: Array,
            value: function() {
              return [1, 2, 3];
            }
          }
        },

      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

</body>

</html>
```

Now in the following fiddle, I made it work by passing the **resources** and **language** object as x-local-test properties.
https://jsfiddle.net/g4evcxzn/2/

But it should work without that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took a look at [`AppLocaleBehavior`'s demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-localize-behavior?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior) and if you actually look at the repo, they use two elements for it, one that [loads the resources from an external json](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-localize-behavior/blob/master/demo/x-translate.html) and one more that has them [locally defined](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-localize-behavior/blob/master/demo/x-local-translate.html) and in the demo, the don't seem to be sharing a cache, just as what's happening to you.

This struck me as odd seeing that they do mention the cache, so I took a look at the [behavior's code](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-localize-behavior/blob/master/app-localize-behavior.html) and found out something interesting, the cache actually exists but it seems its purpose is to prevent loading the same external resource multiple times rather than sharing the `resources` property.

So, if you want to share localization resources on multiple elements the way to go would be having a common resource (let's say we call it `locales.json`) and call the `loadResources` function on every one of them (Since the request is cached you don't need to worry about loading the file multiple times). You could do it on the `attached` callback like this:

```
attached: function () {
  this.loadResources(this.resolveUrl('locales.json'));
}
```

Comment: Note that you also have to define a language property:
`language: { value: 'en' }`
So to have every localized element in the app display the same language, we have to pass down the language to every element. Isn't this an issue ?

Comment: I don't really think it's that big of a problem, I mean, you can actually want different components to be displayed in different languages for whatever reason so you should decide whether you share the language property or not

Comment: What I ended up doing for tackling that problem was to create a behavior that extended Polymer.AppLocalizationBehavior, in there I grab the resource file and set the language. My application would then include the behavior I just defined and I would avoid setting the language everywhere.

Comment: @AlanDávalos actually it is a problem. Now I'm hitting exactly the same issue and I've added the language property everywhere. I don't want to go through all the elements and change the language to all of them for this to work properly. It should work as they documented: add once, localize everywhere.

Answer (score 9):

According the ideas of Jose A. and Jean-Rémi here some example code for copy/paste:

```
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-localize-behavior/app-localize-behavior.html">

    <script>
      MyLocalizeBehaviorImpl = {
        properties: {
          language: {
            value: 'de'
          }
        },
        attached: function() {
          this.loadResources(this.resolveUrl('locales.json'));
        }
      };
      MyLocalizeBehavior = [MyLocalizeBehaviorImpl, Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior]; 
    </script>
```

Include the behavior file in all your custom components and add the behavior:

```
<link rel="import" href="./my-localize-behavior.html">

......

behaviors: [
    MyLocalizeBehavior
],
```

Comment: It's also what I ended doing

Comment: What about browser caching issues with locales.json as done above?  How can one force use of the latest locales file upon change?